# Django ArrayField assert sum to value

Tags: python, django-models

How can I assert/validate/enforce a Django ArrayField sums to a given value.

Example:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    values = ArrayField(models.FloatField(min_value=0.0, 
                                                 max_value=1.0, 
                                                 blank=False), 
                                                 null=False)
```

How can I enforce that all values sum to 1.0, I can't find example usage of a validator.

Is the best way to do this in `save`?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    model = MyModel.objects.filter(id=pk)
    assert np.sum(model.values) == 1.0
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I believe the go-to method for this would be the model clean methods.
 See the docs on [validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

Comment: Are you using django 2.0 with PostgreSQL? In your code you used `models.ArrayField` but the array field is under `django.contrib.postgres.fields` in the current version.

Comment: @pkqxdd Thanks that's a typo I'll fix it in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the `id` field is unnecessary because it is implied by django. Also, the `min_value` and `max_value` arguments only exist in `forms`, not `models`.

Here is one way to achieve your goal:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.admin import site


def validate_sum(array):
    if sum(array) != 1:
        raise ValidationError("The sum of the array must be 1")
    for value in array:
        if not 0<value<1:
            raise ValidationError("%(value)s is not between 0 and 1",params={'value':value})


class MyModel(models.Model):
    values = ArrayField(models.FloatField(),
                        validators=[validate_sum])


site.register(MyModel)
```

This is easier than using the `clean` method as @sytech has proposed.

The documentation of validators can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/)

Comment: I just edited my answer to fix a typo. Also I merged two validators into a same function so it can provide better feedback on `ValidationError`